# How can I stop Chrome from going into debug mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

If the debugging window is open, the debugger starts hitting lines by itself even though there are no set breakpoints.

I have tried using the "Deactivate breakpoints" button and it doesn't make a difference if it is on or off.

This happens on any website.

Comment: There's an option called 'Pause on exceptions' - Turn it off.

Comment: I never knew about this pause on exceptions thing! Can it also pause on anything that returns undefined?

Comment: I have pause on exceptions disabled, and activate break points disabled, and chrome constantly switches into the debugger. I have no break points set either.

Comment: @JohnLittle I'm having the same issue. Breakpoints are deactivated, it's not set to pause on exceptions, and I can't find any manual breakpoints.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You've accidentally set "Pause on Exceptions" to all/uncaught exceptions.

Go to the "Sources" tab. At the top right hand side, toggle the button that looks like the pause symbol surrounded by a hexagon (button on the far right) until the color of the circle turns black to turn it off.

Comment: If the pause symbol isn't blue it may be that you've accidentally marked a line for debugging inspection. This line has a blue arrow to the right that you need to click to turn it off..

Comment: There is also another area if you turned it on before it will always go off when you reload the page and forgot about it.

Under the same tab, there is "XHR Breakpoints" line under "Call Stack" and "Breakpoints".
If you have "Any XHR" checked on this option it will also happen.

Comment: this debugger starting with no action is very annoying and 10 out 10 time i forgot how to stop this because is not very clear at all, Why this obscure way to stop this f.... thing? even if its black it continu to debug

Comment: It would be great if you add images. I'm stuck and your answer isn't helping

Comment: This functionality needs an obvious toggle-switch - 1 hour, still cannot just right-click and turn it off, somehow.  No blue-line#, no lit-up pause button - tried clearing cookes, etc.  Will have to re-install chrome to fix it.

Answer (score 40):

There are a couple of reasons for this:

1. You've toggled on the *Pause On Caught Exceptions* button. So, toggle it off.

   [image]
2. You've toggled a line (or more) to be paused on exception. So, toggle it off.

   [image]

Comment: Just as a FYI; it's the blue pause button not the checkbox in the first picture.

Answer (score 25):

I have made it working...

Please follow the highlighted mark in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: On latest version of Chrome, it kept pausing in debugger. Is there a way to disable it permanently?

Comment: Great finding :) 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh, the thing that appears for a split-second, before disappearing on the next break, after you hit the "play" looking button?  How to get to it before it disappears?

Answer (score 14):

If you were unfamiliar with the tools, it was likely that at some point while in the debugger you toggled a setting that was causing the debugger to stop the application.

I suggest you "Disable all break points":

[image]

Source:

https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the dev tools. (Ctrl + Shift + I)
2. Ctrl + Shift + P
3. Search for "Do not pause on exceptions" and click it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple Google Chrome browser tabs open for the same URL and developer toolbar.

In some other tab, you have set breakpoints which are showing up when you are debugging in the current tab.

Solution: Close the developer toolbar in the other tab or the tab itself.

Comment: This question was answered in the comment, it's because OP has "pause on exceptions" turned on, this can happen by accident.  Chrome developer tools exist on a per-tab basis, and no breakpoints on another tab would cause any interaction on any other tab.

Answer (score 1):

Blue dot still persists.

I only had one tab open and debugging off but the blue dot in the HTML Elements tab persisted.

I left clicked on the blue dot, dragged it down and away and it finally disappeared. I cleared browser cache and it finally fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+F8 to deactivate breakpoints. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem with special site so i just `right click` on javascript file has error that came to `Watch` and click `add to ignore list` and then just click `continue` and never come again

or

can `deactive breakpoint` then click on `resume script executions - f8`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's searching why their chrome debugger is automatically jumping to sources tab on every page load, event though all of the breakpoints/pauses/etc have been disabled.

For me it was the `"breakOnLoad": true` line in VS Code `launch.json` config.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this goofy behavior finally stopped when I unchecked the "Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint" checkbox in Settings...Preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes in any website. It is very easy to remove it. I have attached the image, follow that process, it will be done.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mytFT.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "pause on caught exceptions" checkbox[image]

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me.

Go to `Setting/Preferences` scroll down to `Debugger` check `disable JS` and `asynk stack traces` as shown.

[image]