# Disable debugger statement in the chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to reverse engineer a malicious JavaScript. When I initially load the side, JS code is injected that includes the -debugger- statement and injects breakpoints into my chrome developer console.

Reading through stackoverflow

- Deactivate all breakpoints **does not** help -> script freezes
- Continue debugger afterwards **does not** help -> script freezes
- Mark the script as blackbox **does not** help -> script already frozen. Reload doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how I could analyze / debug the script?

Actually I'm not even able to use the Console from the chrome developer tools because everything freezes.

[Chrome Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDluZ.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831685/how-to-stop-chrome-from-going-into-debug-mode

Comment: Not sure how this helps.

Pause on Exceptions is deactived (see picture attached).
Deactivate all breakpoint by the button beneath causes the same experience.

Comment: See these answers: 1) [Is it possible to avoid breaking on a debugger statement in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53970719), 2) [Chrome how to disable debugger keyword or disable pause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44463814), 3) [Chrome Developer Tools: Way to temporarily ignore or disable all debugger keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36024166)

Answer (score 6):

you probably found the option to right-click the line next to the `debugger` statement and select "Never pause here".

[image: screenshot]

however if blackboxing does not work for you - the above won't work either.
you can use blackbox with a regex pattern, if applicable.
it probably won't work either because malicious codes often use `window.eval`. in that case you override the `window.eval` yourself. for example

```
window.eval=x=>console.log(x);
```

Comment: As they say in the UK, fank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

visit chrome://version/

check v8 version

building v8 from source

edit src/ast/ast.h

```
class DebuggerStatement final : public Statement {
 private:
  friend class AstNodeFactory;
  friend Zone;

--  explicit DebuggerStatement(int pos) : Statement(pos, kDebuggerStatement) {}
++  explicit DebuggerStatement(int pos) : Statement(pos, kEmptyStatement) {}
};
```

building v8 again

diff out.gn/x64.release/d8

patch chromium binary